# getenv(ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE) gets nothing

Tags: php, apache, environment-variables

Before uploading my project to Github, I wanted to hide my API key using an environment variable.

I added this line of code inside .env file

```
API_KEY=MY_API_KEY
```

but when I call API_KEY in my PHP file,

```
$apiKey=getenv('API_KEY');
print_r($apiKey);
```

It shows nothing. And my site crashes because code didn't get the API key.

I tried using SetEnv on the bottom of the `httpd.conf` file.

```
SetEnv API_KEY=MY_API_KEY
```

but this still doesn't work. `print_r()` prints nothing. Just nothing...
What am I doing wrong?

Should the `.env` file be located in the same location as the PHP file?
I am using windows and Xampp Apache is my web server.

Comment: PHP doesn't automatically read .env files on its own, you have to have some code that reads the file. That doesn't explain why the Apache SetEnv version didn't work, but you should concentrate on one or the other.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after updating the `httpd.conf` file?

Comment: @IMSoP When I googled how to use environment variables php I was told I can use .env file and httpd.conf files ... that's why I tried both of them.. I don't have any idea too why my SetEnv doesn't work :( I will try to google the codes that I need for reading .env file. thanks

Comment: @kmoser Actually.. No. I will try it

Comment: Yes, I've seen a lot of confusion about .env flies. Really all they are is another format convention for configuration files, designed to be read at startup *on a development server* and used to simulate real environment variables.

Comment: @kmoser Restarting Apache didn't help me

Comment: Hack if you can't get it working another way, just set the env variable in windows for the user running Apache or maybe system.  Then `exec('echo %API_KEY%', $apikey);` in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

As IMSoP mentioned in comment, I had to do something to force PHP to read my .env file and I solved this issue by installing phpdotenv.
https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv
This package makes available to read .env file.

```
if(file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__));
    $dotenv->load();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using SetEnv on the bottom of the httpd.conf file.
>
> ```
> SetEnv API_KEY=MY_API_KEY
> ```

This method should have worked, except you have used the wrong syntax. There should be no `=` between the key/value pairs. The arguments should be *space* delimited. The above would have set an environment variable called `API_KEY=MY_API_KEY` (instead of `API_KEY`) and assigned an empty string!

It should simply be:

```
SetEnv API_KEY MY_API_KEY
```

After changing `httpd.conf` you would need to restart Apache.

Alternatively, add the directive to a `.htaccess` file in the document root. (Or relevant subdirectory.)

**Reference:**

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I figured that I am not autoloading the lib. For those using CodeIgniter 2/3, you have to add the following code somewhere below your root index.php:

```
/*
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LOAD PHP DOT ENV FILE
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
require_once BASEPATH . 'dotenv/autoloader.php'; // Edit this line

$dotenv = new Dotenv\Dotenv(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

You need to get the files at https://github.com/agungjk/phpdotenv-for-codeigniter/tree/master/system/dotenv and place the dotenv folder wherever you specified its path. In this example, it would be located in /system/dotenv/.